# NSPredicate predicateWithFormat passing in name of attribute

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

Simple question regarding NSPredicate's. I'm trying to construct my predicate with "passed in" values like so :

```
NSPredicate* currentPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ == %@",key,[changesDict valueForKey:@"Id"] ];
```

However, I haven't been able to get this to work correctly. If I insert the actual value I pass through it does work though. So this works :

```
NSPredicate* currentPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contactId == %@",[changesDict valueForKey:@"Id"] ];
```

(Notice i inserted contactId as opposed to the previous example where I pass a string by the same name)

To troubleshoot I NSLogged the two predicates looking at their descriptions and they were different. I'll show them below.

**This is the working one**

```
2013-01-17 10:29:25.513 TestingCoreData[1776:3b03] contactId == "5878"
```

**This is the non working one**

```
2013-01-17 10:29:25.513 TestingCoreData[1776:3b03] "contactId" == "5878"
```

So I can kind of see that it's inserting a string where I really just want the name of the attribute that i'll later be using in the fetch request. But is there any way to accomplish this by passing in values?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For *keys* or *key paths*, you have to use the `%K` format:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", key, [changesDict valueForKey:@"Id"]];
```

(See [Parser Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW2) in the "Predicate Programming Guide".)

Comment: Perfect! Link useful as well. Thanks!