# filtering array with dictionaries using nspredicate fails

Tags: cocoa, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I'm trying to get an NSDictionary out of an NSMutableArray using a predicate:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self createArrayFromCSV:savedCSV withDelimiter:delim firstLineContainsKeys:YES]];

// The method «createArrayFromCSV returns an array of dictionaries

NSLog(@"Array %@", [arr objectAtIndex:0]);  // works fine

// spits out: 

// Array {
//     product = "MyProduct";
//     "id_product" = 29;
// }

// idField and idVal are passed to the method

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%@ == %@)", idField, idVal];

NSLog(@"predicate %@", predicate);

// spits out predicate "id_product" == "29"

NSArray *filtered = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

NSLog(@"Filtered %@", filtered);

// Filtered is always empty
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong???

[SOLVED] Apparently, I made the format string wrong. This works:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K == %@)", idField, idVal];
```

According to this post [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat passing in name of attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385011/nspredicate-predicatewithformat-passing-in-name-of-attribute)

for keys or keypaths, one has to use @K

Comment: Is the value in the dictionary an NSNumber or an NSString?

Comment: That doesn't work immediately after posting a question. Edited just to make clear I solved it for people who read it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently, I made the format string wrong. This works:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K == %@)", idField, idVal];
```

According to this post NSPredicate predicateWithFormat passing in name of attribute

for keys or keypaths, one has to use @K

Comment: Very! This is the exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"email contains[c] %@",searchString];

filteredArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: [[arrayData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] copy]];
```